# Long time tails in Brownian motion

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, brownian-motion

- Rings, D., et al. *Theory of hot Brownian motion*. Soft Matter 7.7 (2011): 3441-3452, [doi:10.1039/C0SM00854K](https://doi.org/10.1039/C0SM00854K).

In this paper the author has mentioned that vorticity diffusion is disregarded due to it's finite time scale. Is the time scale of vorticity diffusion too large when compared to particle motion or is it in the opposite way? Please explain the meaning of the statement.

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that they are assuming that the vorticity diffusion decays *faster* than the timescale for the particle motion, and in fact they say so in the opening section of a later paper: [EPL **96** 60009 (2011)](https://doi.org/10.1209/0295-5075/96/60009).

It is not completely self evident that this assumption is justified, since the vorticity diffusion is responsible for the long-time tail in the particle velocity correlation function, which decays *algebraically* in time. It goes like $t^{-3/2}$ in 3D and like $t^{-1}$ in 2D. You can find more details on this if you look up "long time tails" in the literature. In other words, this contribution to the particle motion does not actually have a well-defined timescale: if you try to write it as $A (t/\tau)^{-3/2}$ there is actually no way of separating the amplitude $A$ from the apparent timescale $\tau$, in the combination $A\tau^{3/2}$. By contrast, for example, with an exponential decay $A\exp(-t/\tau)$ you can separately identify the amplitude $A$ and the timescale $\tau$. So it is hard to justify that this effect of vortex diffusion is "fast" compared with the particle motion.

Nonetheless, perhaps there is some other justification for the assumption that they can neglect the effects of vortex diffusion. It allows them to simplify the way they handle the Langevin equation.

Comment: i believe vorticity diffusion decays similar to heat, and i think you are suggesting that it completely decays in negligible time compared to particle motion to set up a stable condition. Does this in any way justify the second sentence of part 2.2 in https://doi.org/10.1039/C0SM00854K . Basically they just assume the brownian particle to be a stationary surface when talking about fluid fluctuations

Comment: This is what *they* are suggesting in their paper, and it seems to be a standard assumption in the theory of fluctuating hydrodynamics. You can see in my answer that I have a reservation about trying to justify this completely through time scale separation: the vortex diffusion produces a residual long-time tail effect. The authors acknowledge this in their sentence "(This neglects the retardation effects ....)" just above eqn (5) in their paper. In fairness, it is quite usual to neglect long-time tails when  one uses the Langevin equation to describe Brownian motion.